# Unmarshalling xml where the only difference is the schema

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have to unmarshall some xml into java classes.  The xml schemas have been versioned (currently on version 3).  I am receiving two different events that share some common elements, but those common elements could be of different version.  The kicker is, that the versions do not matter to me.  So I will have something like this for the events:

```
<Event1 xmlns:com="http://www.foo.com/Common">
    <com:Name>
         <com:first>Phil<com:/first>
    </com:Name>
</Event1>

<Event2 xmlns:com2="http://www.foo.com/CommonV2">
    <com2:Name>
         <com:first>Phil<com:/first>Roger
    </com2:Name>
</Event2>
```

Since, in this case I wrote code for Event 2 first, my code looks something like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Name", namespace = "http://www.foo.com/CommonV2")
public class Name {    
    private String firstName;

    @XmlElement(name = "first", namespace = "http://www.foo.com/CommonV2")
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can reuse the `Name` class for both `Event1` and `Event2` despite them being made up of different schemas?

Comment: I think the easiest would be an XSLT transformation.